# Is this program logically wrong or have a syntax that I can't seem to find?

Tags: python

I am helping an ex-teacher of mine and need help with this code. I am writing a python program that makes 30 unique cards. 10 are red, 10 are black and 10 are yellow. I have only used red in the code to make it easier to debug. I need to make them with the function which I believe works but then I need to then distribute them and display them at the end but the player's hands cannot be the same as each other and no duplicates in their own hand (as you would in an actual version of this). So I need to set a check system. I really can't find the problem and would appreciate a fresh set of eyes as this can easily fix it or it's out of my own league. Thanks for reading.

P.S
I know I have two player hands for each but that's to add to when a player wins a battle so I can compare who has the most cards and what ones for the end.

I have tried changing it up using different loops and writing it in pseudo code and comparing but don't know what's happening.

```
{import sys, random, time
this = sys.modules[__name__]

def redCardGen():
    for i in range(0,11, 1):
        setattr(this, 'R%s' % i, 'Red Card %s' % i)

def blackCardGen():
    for i in range(0,11, 1):
        setattr(this, 'B%s' % i, 'Black Card %s' % i)

def yellowCardGen():
    for i in range(0,11, 1):
        setattr(this, 'Y%s' % i, 'Yellow Card %s' % i)

redCardGen()

blackCardGen()
yellowCardGen()

breaker = 0

player1Hand = []
player2Hand = []
WinnnerDeck = []
WinnerDeck2 = []

Red = [R1, R2, R3, R4, R5, R6, R7, R8, R9, R10]



play = input("Would you like to play the game?: ")
if(play == "yes"):
    print("Okay, then lets play!")
else:
    exit()
for i in range(0,6, 1):
    player1Hand.append(random.choice(Red))
    player2Hand.append(random.choice(Red))
breaker1 = 0
while(breaker1 == 0):
    if (player1Hand != 5):
        player1Hand.append(random.choice(Red))
        player2Hand.append(random.choice(Red))
    elif ((len(set(player1Hand))==1) and (len(set(player2Hand))==1)):
        player1Hand.pop()
        player2Hand.pop()
        player1Hand.append(random.choice(Red))
        player2Hand.append(random.choice(Red))
    elif ((len(set(player1Hand and player2Hand)) == 1)):
        player1Hand.pop()
        player2Hand.pop()
        player1Hand.append(random.choice(Red))
        player2Hand.append(random.choice(Red))
    else:
        breaker1 = 1

print(player1Hand)
print(player2Hand)}
```

There are no errors so I don't think that it is a syntax problem but rather a logical error.
My expected outcome is to have two player hands with random cards in but none are the same.

Comment: `if player1Hand != 5` player1Hand shouldn't be a list ?

Comment: ah should I of said {if len(player1Hand) != 5}

Comment: In fact, you overcomplicated the problem. Use random.shuffle() to shuffle your deck. Trying to get random elements from a set without duplicates the way you do is always a mess.

Comment: Okay, I will try this. Could you give an example on how to do this without any duplicates in each hand?

Answer (score 1):

An example of cards distribution using random.shuffle() :

```
import random

deck = ["R1", "R2", "R3", "R4", "R5", "R6", "R7", "R8", "R9", "R10"]
random.shuffle(deck)

player1_hand = deck[:5]
player2_hand = deck[5:10]
print(player1_hand)
print(player2_hand)
```

Returns :

```
['R4', 'R2', 'R10', 'R5', 'R1']
['R7', 'R8', 'R9', 'R3', 'R6']
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you explain the deck[:5] and deck [5:10]

Comment: It is just basic slicing. Read this https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html?highlight=slice . `deck[:5]` takes the 5 first elements of list deck and `deck [5:10]` the 5 next ones.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to simulate a deck of cards, it would be best to have a list that represents it so you can shuffle it and use a function that draws a card from from the top (and removes it):

```
import random

cardDeck    = [C+str(n+1) for C in "RBY" for n in range(10)]
player1Hand = []
player2Hand = []

# deal cards
random.shuffle(cardDeck)
for _ in range(5):
    player1Hand.append(cardDeck.pop())
    player2Hand.append(cardDeck.pop())

print(player1Hand) # ['Y3', 'B10', 'Y5', 'R2', 'Y8']
print(player2Hand) # ['Y10', 'B6', 'Y1', 'R9', 'R7']
```

This approach will make it easier to draw more cards from the deck without worrying about duplicates.